# Compile and execute AST using pybind11 or Python C API

Tags: python, c++, abstract-syntax-tree, python-c-api, pybind11

I would like to translate this Python code into C++ code using Pybind11 or directly the Python C API:

```python
import ast

code = "print('Hello World!')"

code_ast = ast.parse(code, mode="exec") # "code" being a string containing code
# ... perform some modifications on "code_ast"
exec(compile(code_ast, filename="<ast>", mode="exec"))
```

Here is what I have currently using Pybind11:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include "pybind11/embed.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

std::string code = "print('Hello World!')";

py::module ast = py::module::import("ast");
py::module builtins = py::module::import("builtins");

py::object code_ast = ast.attr("parse")(code, "<unknown>", "exec");
// ... perform some modifications on "code_ast"
py::object compiled_code = builtins.attr("compile")(code_ast, "<ast>", "exec");
builtins.attr("exec")(compiled_code);
```

Unfortunately, the last line of C++ code raises a runtime error: `SystemError: frame does not exist`.

I'm not sure I understand this error, I tried to pass the `globals` and `locals` to `exec`, it didn't solve the issue.

**EDIT**: When passing `globals`, it says: `SystemError: <built-in function globals> returned NULL without setting an error`

Any idea on how to achieve this properly?

Comment: You should post a [MCVE], the frame object is missing for some reason, that has nothing to do with your posted code. Your posted code is fine.

Comment: I have no frame object in my code, it's an internal object of the Python interpreter. The code posted is not fine, the interpreter was complaining because I wasn't passing the global namespace to the `exec` function.

Comment: The only thing missing is the `include` of the needed header files, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer, I wasn't using the `globals` function from Pybind11, but the built-in one from Python (`builtins.attr("globals")()`).

This is the working version:

```c++
py::module ast = py::module::import("ast");
py::module builtins = py::module::import("builtins");

py::object code_ast = ast.attr("parse")(code, "<unknown>", "exec");
// ... perform some modifications on "code_ast"
py::object compiled_code = builtins.attr("compile")(code_ast, "<ast>", "exec");
builtins.attr("exec")(compiled_code, py::globals());
```